# MS Access: Compare 2 tables with duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables which look like this:

T1:

```
ID  |  Date  |  Hour
```

T2:

```
ID  |  Date  |  Hour
```

I basically need to join these tables when their IDs, dates, and hours match. However, I only want to return the results from table 1 that do not match up with the results in table 2.

I know this seems simple, but where I'm stuck is the fact that there are multiple rows in table 1 that match up with table 2 (there are multiple intervals for any given hour). I need to return all of these intervals so long as they do not fall within the same hour period in table 2.

Example data:

T1:

```
 1  |  1/1/2011  |  1
 1  |  1/1/2011  |  1  
 1  |  1/1/2011  |  1   
 1  |  1/1/2011  |  2
```

T2:

```
 1  |  1/1/2011  |  1
 1  |  1/1/2011  |  1
```

My expected result set for this would be the last 2 rows from T1. Can anyone point me on the right track?.

Comment: The third row of `T1` matches with at least one row in `T2` and you are asking for the last two rows of `T1` to be returned.  Does that mean that you wish to return one and only one row for each match that does occur no matter how often that match occurs?  Or are you actually just chasing the last row of `T1` (which is what you are asking for elsewhere in your Question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.date = t1.date and t2.hour = t1.hour
                 );
```

EDIT:

I misread the question.  This is very hard to do in MS Access. But, you can come close.  The following returns the distinct rows in table 1 that do not have equivalent numbers in table 2:

```
select t1.id, t1.date, t1.hour, (t1.cnt - t2.cnt)
from (select id, date, hour, count(*) as cnt
      from t1
      group by id, date, hour
     ) t1 left join
     (select id, date, hour, count(*) as cnt
      from t2
      group by id, date, hour
     ) t2 left join
     on t2.id = t1.id and t2.date = t1.date and t2.hour = t1.hour
where t2.cnt < t1.cnt;
```

Comment: can you do this via MS ACCESS?

Comment: That query is valid in MS Access -- well, you might need to escape the column names, but that is all.

Comment: tried it but it gets me the last row in table 1. i need to get the last 2 rows.

Comment: @ErnestTatco . . . I really did misread the question.  Your problem is really hard if the tables have no unique identifier.  Hopefully, the edited solution is close enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sir Gordon, tried it but still gets the last row. I'll try to edit you answer and see if it works.

Comment: "However, I only want to return the results from table 1 that do not match up with the results in table 2."  The last row *should* be returned.

Comment: Oh, i get it. Thanks again i'll if i can get the last 2 rows.